# Why do I get white screen while uploading the maps from Mapbox?

Tags: android, kotlin, mapbox

[image]

Hello, I am very new to Android Studio developing and Mapbox package. Please do not judge me very strict, I really would like to understand working with Maps, but I am facing the same problem all the time and I could not find the solution in the Mapbox documentation, I cannot see the map, only the white screen instead, where could be my mistake that causes it?

Here is my Second Activity.xml layout code I use for this activity

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:mapbox="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Activity_Second" >

    <fragment
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapView
            android:id="@+id/mapView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            mapbox:mapbox_cameraZoom="12" />
    </fragment>

    <androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        tools:openDrawer="start"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_activity__second"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_activity__second"
        app:menu="@menu/activity__second_drawer" />

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I should use Drawer Layout by the application logic for the future, I thought this causes the problem. Then I decided to wrap all the elements into the relative layout, later I put the Mapbox attributes into the fragment, but it still does not help.

Here is my Second_Activity.kt file

```
package com.cz.brnobicycle

import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.os.Handler
import android.view.Menu
import android.view.MenuItem
import android.widget.Toast
import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar
import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
import androidx.navigation.findNavController
import androidx.navigation.ui.AppBarConfiguration
import androidx.navigation.ui.navigateUp
import androidx.navigation.ui.setupActionBarWithNavController
import androidx.navigation.ui.setupWithNavController
import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
import com.example.brnobikeapp.constants.CompanionString.Companion.DEFAULT_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS
import com.example.brnobikeapp.constants.CompanionString.Companion.DEFAULT_MAX_WAIT_TIME
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth
import com.mapbox.android.core.location.*
import com.mapbox.android.core.permissions.PermissionsListener
import com.mapbox.android.core.permissions.PermissionsManager
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.Mapbox
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.annotations.MarkerOptions
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.camera.CameraPosition
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.camera.CameraUpdateFactory
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.constants.TelemetryConstants
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.geometry.LatLng
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.location.modes.CameraMode
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.location.modes.RenderMode
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapView
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapboxMap
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.OnMapReadyCallback
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.location.LocationComponentActivationOptions
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.Style


class Activity_Second : AppCompatActivity(), OnMapReadyCallback, PermissionsListener {

    private lateinit var mapView: MapView
    private lateinit var map: MapboxMap
    private lateinit var permissionsManager: PermissionsManager
    private lateinit var locationEngine: LocationEngine
    private lateinit var callback: LocationChangeListeningCallback

    private lateinit var appBarConfiguration: AppBarConfiguration
    var mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        Mapbox.getInstance(
            this,
            "pk.eyJ1Ijoia29zdGFyZXYxOCIsImEiOiJjazhwb3o2OXEwMTVnM2ZueW55ZXo4Y2lwIn0.cj2bNacMGkpwEAyPclBXVA"
        )

        setContentView(R.layout.activity__second)
        mapView = findViewById(R.id.mapView)
        mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        mapView.getMapAsync(this)


        val toolbar: Toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar)
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)

        val fab: FloatingActionButton = findViewById(R.id.fab)
        fab.setOnClickListener { view ->
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                .setAction("Action", null).show()
        }
        val drawerLayout: DrawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout)
        val navView: NavigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view)
        val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
        // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
        // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
        appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(
            setOf(
                R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_gallery, R.id.nav_slideshow
            ), drawerLayout
        )
        setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
        navView.setupWithNavController(navController)
    }


    override fun onMapReady(mapboxMap: MapboxMap) {
        this.map = mapboxMap

        mapboxMap.setStyle(Style.MAPBOX_STREETS) {

            /*
            mapboxMap?.addMarker(
                MarkerOptions()
                    .position(LatLng(49.197146, 16.603248))
                    .title("Station 1")
            )
            mapboxMap?.addMarker(
                MarkerOptions()
                    .position(LatLng(49.198197, 16.613942))
                    .title("Station 2")
            )
            mapboxMap?.addMarker(
                MarkerOptions()
                    .position(LatLng(49.192125, 16.613105))
                    .title("Station 3")
            )
            mapboxMap?.addMarker(
                MarkerOptions()
                    .position(LatLng(49.178225, 16.621644))
                    .title("Station 4")
            )

             */
        }
    }


private fun enableLocationComponent(loadedMapStyle: Style) {
    if (PermissionsManager.areLocationPermissionsGranted(this)) {
        val locationComponentActivationOptions = LocationComponentActivationOptions.builder(this, loadedMapStyle)
            .useDefaultLocationEngine(false)
            .build()
        map.locationComponent.apply {
            activateLocationComponent(locationComponentActivationOptions)
            isLocationComponentEnabled = true                       // Enable to make component visible
            cameraMode = CameraMode.TRACKING                        // Set the component's camera mode
            renderMode = RenderMode.COMPASS                         // Set the component's render mode
        }
        initLocationEngine()
    } else {
        permissionsManager = PermissionsManager(this)
        permissionsManager.requestLocationPermissions(this)
    }
}

    private fun initLocationEngine() {
        locationEngine = LocationEngineProvider.getBestLocationEngine(this)
        val request = LocationEngineRequest
            .Builder(DEFAULT_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS)
            .setPriority(LocationEngineRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)
            .setMaxWaitTime(DEFAULT_MAX_WAIT_TIME)
            .build()
        locationEngine.requestLocationUpdates(request, callback, mainLooper)
        locationEngine.getLastLocation(callback)
    }

    override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode: Int, permissions: Array<out String>, grantResults: IntArray) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)
        permissionsManager.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)
    }

    private inner class LocationChangeListeningCallback :
        LocationEngineCallback<LocationEngineResult> {

        override fun onSuccess(result: LocationEngineResult?) {
            result?.lastLocation ?: return //BECAREFULL HERE, IF NAME LOCATION UPDATE DONT USER -> val resLoc = result.lastLocation ?: return
            if (result.lastLocation != null){
                val lat = result.lastLocation?.latitude!!
                val lng = result.lastLocation?.longitude!!
                val latLng = LatLng(lat, lng)

                if (result.lastLocation != null) {
                    map.locationComponent.forceLocationUpdate(result.lastLocation)
                    val position = CameraPosition.Builder()
                        .target(latLng)
                        .zoom(13.0) //disable this for not follow zoom
                        .tilt(10.0)
                        .build()
                    map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(position))
                    Toast.makeText(this@Activity_Second, "Location update : $latLng", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
            }

        }

        override fun onFailure(exception: Exception) {}
    }

    override fun onExplanationNeeded(permissionsToExplain: MutableList<String>?) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Permission not granted!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }

    override fun onPermissionResult(granted: Boolean) {
        if (granted) {
            map.getStyle {
                enableLocationComponent(it)
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Permission not granted!! app will be EXIT", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            Handler().postDelayed({
                finish()
            }, 3000)
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.activity__second, menu)
        return true
    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        if(item.itemId == R.id.settings){
            val intent = Intent(this, SettingsActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        } else if(item.itemId == R.id.logout){
            mAuth.signOut()
            finish()
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }
    override fun onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed()
        mAuth.signOut()
    }

    override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
        val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
        return navController.navigateUp(appBarConfiguration) || super.onSupportNavigateUp()
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("MissingPermission")
    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        mapView.onStart()
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        mapView.onResume()
    }

    override fun onPause() {
        super.onPause()
        mapView.onPause()
    }

    override fun onStop() {
        super.onStop()
        mapView.onStop()
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        mapView.onDestroy()
    }

    override fun onLowMemory() {
        super.onLowMemory()
        mapView.onLowMemory()
    }

    override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)
        mapView.onSaveInstanceState(outState)
    }
}
```

At some forums, there was written, that the problem is in the manifest, I added some permissions in the beginning, but it still did not resolve the problem,

And the manifest I use for this app

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.cz.brnobicycle">

    <permission
        android:name="info.androidhive.googlemapsv2.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="info.androidhive.googlemapsv2.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".SettingsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_settings"></activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Activity_Second"
            android:label="@string/title_activity__second"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest
```

Thank you

Comment: I would be glad if someone could recommend me good mapbox tutorials as well, because all that I found had either some version problems either it did not work in practice. Thank you

Comment: Delete zoom lines

Comment: zoom(13.0) and  mapbox:mapbox_cameraZoom="12"

Comment: Thank you, I tried it now, but still the white screen

Comment: I feel like something wrong is with the layouts in the XML file,

Comment: You have activated Google map API?

Comment: I am using mapbox API

Answer (score 0):

It appears that this may be an issue with your access token. Are you using your default access token or another token? When I try to load a map using your access token, the map shows the same way, blank. However, when I use my default token I am able to see the map load with no issue.